# my internet is suddenly slow

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, 64-bit, intel, multi-core

im running Ubuntu 12.10 and it works like a charm... but one problem, when i updated my software everything seemed OK until i noticed that my internet speed very slow. i had about 5-6 MBPS but it suddenly changed to 130 kbps max speed no higher, so to see if it was my internet i booted up windows to see my speed on there and it went right back to 5-6 MBPS.
rebooted to Ubuntu and back to 130 Kbps ??? can anyone help me with this. it took 2 days to download team fortress, when it usually takes only about 54-6 hours... please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have any other application running in the background eating up all your bandwidth. 
Install nethogs:

```
  sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

. Then open terminal, type -

```
  sudo nethogs
```

This will bring up a list from where you can identify which program is using maximum internet. Kill the process which is using the max bandwidth.

Still if everything is fine and if you are using an external LAN card then it might be a driver problem.

Install "firestarter", if you want to monitor which ports are being used or to check whether someone is hacking into your system. Check whether you have "Transmission" downloading any torrent files or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about net speed inside Steam. One way to tweak it is by changing your download region. Go to *Steam > Settings > Downloads + Cloud* and change your *Download Region* to one closest to you.
[image: Steam Settings]